# How to use multiple baseURL axios in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, react-hooks

I am having a config file . where i am setting the baseURL for the entire app and also saving the bearer token for the entire API requests. Here i am in situation to add another api . I dont know how to add another baseURL & use this on my API requests.Here i am sharing the code of what i have done.

**BASE URL FILE:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = http://localhost:3000/summary;

const setAuthToken = (token) => {
  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  } else {
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
  }
};

export default setAuthToken;
```

**API ACTION FILE:**

```
export const login = ({ email, password }) => async (dispatch) => {

  const userData = {
    username: email,
    password,
  };

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/license-api/auth/login', userData, config);
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data.token,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAIL,
    });

  }
};
```

i need to add another url like this in BASE URL FILE

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = http://localhost:6000/profile
```

how to add this one and use this in API action file.

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create two different client instances with different values? https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#creating-an-instance

Comment: HI , how to use that instance in the action fie?

Comment: Import it from where it's defined, as with anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said you could create two [instances of axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) and use them as needed:

In you **BASE URL** file:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const setAuthToken = (token) => {
  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  } else {
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
  }
};

const mainAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/summary'
});

const profileAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:6000/profile'
});

export default setAuthToken;
export { mainAxios, profileAxios };
```

Then in your **API ACTION** file:

```
import { profileAxios } from 'path/to/baseurl';

export const login = ({ email, password }) => async (dispatch) => {

  const userData = {
    username: email,
    password,
  };

  try {
    const res = await profileAxios.post('/license-api/auth/login', userData, config);
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data.token,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAIL,
    });

  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code works well. I don't see where setAuthToken is called so if you don't want to call setAuthToken manually then you might want to do this.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { config } from "./config";

const pythonAPI = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.pythonServerUrl,
});

const nodeApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.nodeServerUrl,
});

const setToken = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
  if (token) {
    pythonAPI.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Basic ${token}`;
  } else {
    delete pythonAPI.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
  }
};

const pythonApi = {};

pythonApi.get = async (url) => {
  setToken();
  return pythonAPI.get(url).catch((e) => e.response);
};

pythonApi.post = async (url, data) => {
  setToken();
  return pythonAPI.post(url, data).catch((e) => e.response);
};

export { pythonApi, nodeApi };
```